# Una variable local de referencia es destruida cuando finaliza la ejecución del método?

Tags: java

Premisas:

1. Los objetos no referenciados son marcados por el garbage Collector y serán borrados.
2. La información almacenada en una variable local desaparece en cuanto finalice la ejecución de un método.

Si declaro una variable de referencia en un método que apunte al objeto 'x' y termino la ejecución de ese método sin hacer que la variable apunte a null:

¿Seguirá el objeto 'x' teniendo una referencia (en el código de dicho método) que apunte hacia él y que por tanto no pueda ser marcado por el garbage collector, aunque ya no se necesite más a lo largo del programa?

o

¿Al finalizar el método desaparece la información de la variable local de referencia de forma que el objeto 'x' al que apunta pueda ser marcado por el garbage?

Gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4138213/5525964

Comment: Vaya, gracias. Es clavado a lo que buscaba. Mil gracias